# Как реализовать добавление линии в GraphicsScene на подобие добавления фигур в Ворде (pyqt5)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyside2

Как реализовать добавление линии в `GraphicsScene` на подобие добавления фигур в Ворде (можно растягивать, увеличивать, передвигать) + линия должна иметь свой класс(видно использовать "setLine" не получится)
[Как привязать к программе отрисовку фигур(линии, прямоугольника), используя класс с двумя координатами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1189911/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%80%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: посмотрите примеры: [раз](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-elasticnodes-example.html) [два](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-diagramscene-example.html). [Полный список](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-graphicsview.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, в котором используется два элемента: HandleItem и PipeItem. 
Каждый управляет своей задачей и обновляет положение других элементов.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class HandleItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsPathItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addEllipse(QtCore.QRectF(-3, -3, 6, 6))
        
        self.setPath(path)

        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)

        self._pipe_item = None

    @property
    def pipe_item(self):
        return self._pipe_item

    @pipe_item.setter
    def pipe_item(self, item):
        self._pipe_item = item

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionChange and self.isEnabled():
            ip = self.pipe_item.mapFromScene(value)
            self.pipe_item.end_pos = ip
        elif change == QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemSelectedChange:
            color = QtCore.Qt.red if value else QtCore.Qt.black
            self.setPen(QtGui.QPen(color, 2, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine))
            self.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(color)) 
            
        return super().itemChange(change, value)


class PipeItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsPathItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)

        self._end_pos = QtCore.QPointF()

        self._handle = HandleItem()
        self.handle.pipe_item = self

        self.end_pos = QtCore.QPointF(100, 100)        
        self.handle.setPos(self.end_pos)

        self.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.blue, 1, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine))
        self.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 255, 155))  

    @property
    def handle(self):
        return self._handle

    @property
    def end_pos(self):
        return self._end_pos

    @end_pos.setter
    def end_pos(self, p):
        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.lineTo(p)
        stroke = QtGui.QPainterPathStroker()
        stroke.setWidth(3)                         
        self.setPath(stroke.createStroke(path))
        self._end_pos = p

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        option.state &= ~QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected
        super().paint(painter, option, widget)

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemSceneHasChanged:
            if self.scene():
                self.scene().addItem(self.handle)
        elif change == QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionChange and self.isEnabled():
            p = self.mapToScene(self.end_pos)
            self.handle.setPos(p)
        return super().itemChange(change, value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(sceneRect=QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 200, 200))
    item = PipeItem()
    scene.addItem(item)
    view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(scene)
    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    window.setCentralWidget(view)
    window.resize(640, 480)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Буду разбираться, немного похоже как в Ворде, попытаюсь сделать две точки к линии